# Build Error: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" | openssl base64', CurrentDirectory=''

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I got this error while building my project to android.

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" |
>   openssl base64', CurrentDirectory=''
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   () (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.DoesCommandExist
>   (System.String command) (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:134)
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_DebugKeyHash () (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:41)
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.IsSetupProperly () (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:22)
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.XCodePostProcess.OnPostProcessBuild
>   (BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookPostprocess.cs:49)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Here are some more detail of my app:

i made a basic 2d game hwo just contain ongui function i have added facebook sdk, google ads sdk, i have installed all the android sdk from sdk manager, i have installed admob plugin vntis. but i havent used facebook sdk. and my pc is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there seems like you have a **path mismatch** change your path from
C:\Windows\System32

To

C:\Windows\System32;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\\bin;C:\OpenSSL\bin

Example

C:\Windows\System32;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_49\bin;C:\OpenSSL\bin

Comment: my path is C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin

Comment: properties ->advance system setting->enviroment variables ->system variables->"path"

Comment: i dont have openssl or something like that in that directory

Comment: http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1L.exe here is a n installer for OpenSSL